# Loading Tensorflow model in different session

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm a bit new to all this so could you please help me? I tried finding the answer to this question but found nothing.

I'm trying to load Tensorflow model in python in a separate function so I can use the model in a loop without having to load it in every iteration of the for loop.

This is my code now:

```
def load_network():
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)    
    return (prediction)



def use_neural_network(data, prediction):         
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_name+'.meta')
        saver.restore(sess,model_name)
        pred = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x: data})
        pred = np.asarray(pred)
    return pred


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result=[]
    Load= start_network()
    for i in data:
        result.append(use_neural_network(i,Load))
```

And I would like to get something like this:

```
def load_network():
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)    
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_name+'.meta')
        saver.restore(sess,model_name)

    return (prediction)



def use_neural_network(data, prediction):         
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        pred = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x: data})
        pred = np.asarray(pred)
    return pred


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result=[]
    Load= start_network()
    for i in data:
        result.append(use_neural_network(i,Load))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally what you're trying to achieve is easily doable and you're on the right track. In the main block you have `start_network()` instead of `load_network()` as in your first line. I'd also recommend against using `Load` as a variable name but that should not be a problem. Also the TensorFlow Session (`sess` in your code) should either be a global variable, or you should initialize it either in the main block or in the `load_network()` function and then pass it on to the `use_neural_network()` function. The way it's currently written the two `sess` variables in the two functions are local and therefore refer to different sessions.

If you want to avoid having to use the `neural_network_model( x )` function, that is building the model at the beginning, you might want to *freeze* the model and load it that way, with the architecture embedded as well. Easiest to follow a guide on that, like [this one](https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc).